# How to show rational points of finite order on an elliptic cure are closed under addition

Tags: elliptic-curves

I would like to show that rational points of finite order on an elliptic curve are closed under addition.

If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are rational (actually integral) points of finite order, say $nP_1= O$ and $mP_2=O$,

I would like to say:

$$O=nmP_1 +nmP_2 =nm(P_1+P_2)$$

My question is how do I know the rightmost equality holds. Thanks

Comment: $nmP_1$ actually means $P_1 + P_1 + \cdots P_1$, and addition on the curve is commutative, so...

Comment: @rogerl Thanks, that's what I thought and how I have the leftmost equality. My question is regarding the validity of saying this equals nm times this third point (P_1+P_2) where addition is on the curve. Maybe I am making too much of this, but by definition we know a point of finite order is as you say. I am stuck on the right side.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rational points of an elliptic curve are an abelian group, i.e. a $\mathbf Z$-module and the points of finite order its torsion subgroup. The last equality is part of the distributive laws for modules.